# How to write a workflow to move the files from one folder to another (in the same doc library)?

Tags: sharepoint

I've a document library. Within this library, I've two folders. I'd like to run a workflow which moves the file from one folder to another when an item is changed.  I'm using update list item action. can anyone please tell me, how to write the path and name with full workflow?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should call rest api(post request) to move file.

Sample endpoint:

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/mydoc/testdoc.txt')/MoveTo(newUrl='/mydoc2/testdoc.txt',flags='1')
```

Call rest api in workflow.

https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-and-post-rest-api/